# How to get the last index looping over an array and decrease it on the next iteration

Tags: javascript

I am sending information looping over an array that is in another array using broadcast function.
I need to broadcast the message in the reverse order without reversing the array I am looping over. If you have any ideas let me know.

```
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  array.map((message, index, arr) => {
    broadcast(clients, JSON.stringify(message));
    if (index == array.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Use a simple for loop?

Comment: my mistake , this is an array from an array

Comment: Honestly the simplest solution here seems to be `array.slice().reverse().forEach(...)`. But I'm suspicious with regards to the somewhat strange interval wrapper.

Comment: this is an array of an array brodcasting in an interval of one second

Comment: Please add an actual, *copyable* example of `array`, and explain a bit more how that interval is relevant and why it's impossible to reverse the array.

Comment: here is the requirement. Once the websocket listeneris ready to recieve connections, the server must loop over this array
['call-1', 'call-2'] and send the following data to the connected client(s) in this order {ID:
'call__2', duration: 2} then {ID: 'call__1', duration: 1}
After 1 second: loop over this array ['call-2', 'call-3'] and send the following data to the
connected client(s) in this order {ID: 'call__3', duration: 3} and then {ID: 'call__2',
duration: 2}

Comment: How do you get from (for example) `call-2` to `{ID: 'call__2', duration: 2}`? And then, how does this array expand? Meaning, where is `call-3` coming from?

Comment: I think each call has its id and the duration of the call. basically each call is an object. so we have an array of calls. we need to chunk it into two calls wich makes it into arrrays inside of an array.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm giving up. Please just add example data and all required details to the question. As it stands I don't think it's answerable.

Comment: your answer works for me. if you post it I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Use normal for loop.

```js
function interval(){
  let arrLen= yourArr.length;
  setInterval(() => {
   for(i=arrLen-1; i>=0; i--){
    broadcast(clients, JSON.stringify(yourArr[i])
    if (i == 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
   }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: looping over an array that is in another array

Comment: Pardon. Didn't get you. I am looping over only yourArr and not any other array. How is it looping over an array that is in another array.